# RVM breaks gems, looking in wrong Ruby version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, rvm, compass-sass

I have ruby 2.2.0 and I use RVM for a project that requires 2.0.0

After installing RVM I tried to use sass or compass gems outside the project and got this:

```
$ compass watch
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'compass' (>= 0) among 49 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/compass:22:in `<main>'
```

I tried removing RVM and reinstalling the gems and all worked fine, but I need it for the project.

Why is it looking in `2.0` folder? When I do `rvm info` I get `ruby-2.2.0:`

---

Update:

```
$ which ruby
/Users/ilyo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby


$ which compass
/usr/bin/compass


$rvm info

ruby-2.2.0:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin ilyo-audyx.local 14.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.10/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.9 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "4 days 7 hours 57 minutes 33 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/ilyo/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.2.0p0"
    date:         "2014-12-25"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin14"
    patchlevel:   "2014-12-25 revision 49005"
    full_version: "ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/ilyo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0"
    ruby:         "/Users/ilyo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/ilyo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/ilyo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/ilyo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/ilyo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/ilyo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin:/Users/ilyo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin:/Users/ilyo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin:/Users/ilyo/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/ilyo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/ilyo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/ilyo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0:/Users/ilyo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/ilyo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/ilyo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your usual Ruby 2.2.0 is not installed by RVM, only version 2.0.0 installed for that particular project is? That would be the problem, because outside of that projects directory, RVM sets up the system-installed Ruby 2.0.0 that comes standard with OS X as the default. I would suggest uninstalling your 2.2.0, then installing it again through RVM with  `rvm install 2.2.0` and making it the default with `rvm use 2.2.0 --default`.

Comment: 2.2.0 already installed through RVM. Making it default did not help.

Comment: Try running `rvm info`, `which ruby` and `which compass`, and add the output to your question.

Comment: Your `compass` seems to have been installed under the system Ruby; the binary should be located in your RVM installation (`~/.rvm/...`), not in `/usr/bin`. Try `rvm use system`, see whether `gem list --local` shows compass and remove it with `gem uninstall compass`. Then switch back into your default Ruby and reinstall it there.

Comment: @janfoeh by default ruby you mean the rvm ruby, right? How do I switch back to it?

Comment: `rvm use default` loads whatever Ruby you made the default with `ruby use <version> --default`, which in your case should be your Ruby 2.2.0.

Comment: I switched to `system`, compass works, but it does not appear in the `gem list` and I can't uninstall it.

Comment: If you cannot remember how you installed it, I would move the binary out of the way with `sudo mv /usr/bin/compass /usr/bin/disabled.compass`. Now you can install compass in your default ruby if you haven't done so already, and running `compass watch` will execute the correct `compass`.